# equality constrained least square fitting using python

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone help me for writing a python script? The problem is stated below.

I need to perform a equality constrained linear least square fitting of some linear equations. For a specific linear equation, the matrix equation looks like [Y]*{nX1}=[X]*{nXm}[P]_{mX1}, where Y and P are vectors and X is a matrix and n, m are dimension of the matrix. Further, there is a equality constraint on P which is Sum(P(i))=0.0. Do anyone have idea how do I proceed to solve that? Which function of python is suitable for this? I saw few of discussions on scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp() function but use of this function is not very straightforward.

However, I can easily do the unconstrained least square fitting of the above problem by using numpy. Here is the small script.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import arange,array,ones,linalg
x = np.random.randn(500,3)
A=matrix([[3.0, 4.0, -7.0],[4.0, -5.0, 1.0],[3.0, 2.0, -5.0]])
y=A*x.T
w=linalg.lstsq(x,y.T)[0]
print w.T
```

Here I had generated a random vector x and then generated vector y by matrix multiplication of A and x.T. Then I use the x and y vectors and evaluated the elements of matrix  A. The above script perfectly reproduces the matrix A. This gives me the confidence that the lsf works. However, it is just least square fitting. There is no constraints.

Another thing, is it possible to convert constrained lsf problem to unconstrained lsf problem. If so, then I can use the above script. The method of lagrange multiplier is one of the possible choice. However, I am facing difficulty to evaluate the multiplier for my problem. This is because, the equation contains large no of variables. If there is

By the way the similar function for constrained lsf in MATLAB is lsqlin.

I am struggling with this for last week. Please help me out in this regard.  If you have any other suggestions then that will also be great.

Best wishes

Answer (score 4):

Equality-constrained linear least-squares fitting, for dense matrices, is currently (Scipy 1.5) available in Python with a direct call to the relevant LAPACK routine [scipy.linalg.lapack.dgglse](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.dgglse.html). The LAPACK documentation of DGGLSE is [here](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node28.html).

As an example, the solution to the problem

```
min ||A @ x - b||
subject to  C @ x = d
```

can be obtained using the Python code

```
from scipy.linalg import lapack

# Define the matrices as usual, then
x = lapack.dgglse(A, C, b, d)[3]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is not too large, you can solve it by solving an equivalent linear system. Suppose you write your constrained least-squares problem in the form

```
min 1/2 |Ax - b|^2
subject to  Bx = c,
```

in the Euclidian norm (it really sucks that StackOverflow doesn't support MathJax!) The factor 1/2 is just there for convenience. The solution x to the above problem (assuming there is one) can equivalently be found by solving the linear system

```
[ I   A  0   ] [ r ]   [ b ]
[ A.T 0  B.T ] [ x ] = [ 0 ]
[ 0   B  0   ] [ y ]   [ c ]
```

where the zero blocks have appropriate sizes, `.T` indicates transposition and `I` is the identity matrix of appropriate size. You're looking for the middle segment of the solution vector. Note that the above matrix is symmetric but it's indefinite so if you don't have anything specialized, you'll have to use the LU factorization to solve the system (it's OK but you could save about half of the work.) You can't use Cholesky.

If your problem is large, you can also use [MINRES](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.minres.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.minres) to solve the above system without actually assembling or factorizing it. You'll only need to provide a `LinearOperator` that computes products with this matrix.

I also discovered: https://gist.github.com/fabianp/915461 (but haven't tested).

Comment: I've tested and read through the Github gist you linked, it appears to be correct. The book it's based on is a very high quality Numerical Analysis textbook, worth a read!

Answer (score 0):

You may try 'the method of weight' mentioned in 'matrix computations' by Golub and van Loan, it is an approximate method which only need the design matrix.